# In python, how to overload return/get based on return type?

Tags: python, overloading, constructor-overloading

In python, is it possible to overload the return type? Basically, I'm trying to see if I can do something like this:

```
class Node(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.value = 5

   def hello(self):
       print('hello')

class Container(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.node = Node()

   def __setattr__(self, name, value):
       if self.__dict__.get(name, False) and name == 'node':
          obj = getattr(self, name)
          obj.value = value
       else:
          self.__dict__[name] = value

       # some method overloading... to return base on type

container = Container()
container.node = 3
print (container.node.value) # outputs 3
int_val = 0
int_val = container.node  # assign int_val to 3
container.node.hello() # prints out 'hello'
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "return based on type". There is nothing specifying any types in your code; you just have expressions setting and accessing the value of `container.node`.

Comment: You might be able to make `Node` an `int` subclass (with a `hello` method), then make `container.node` a `property` that stores a `Node` when given a `int`.  That seems like a lot of work for no real benefit, plus I'm not sure how one would go about subclassing `int` sensibly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible.  You can define an `__int__` method to specify what should happen when `int` is called on an instance of your class, so that `int(container.node)` would be 3.  But you can't have `container.node` actually *be* 3, while the `container.node` part of `container.node.hello()` is something else.  Evaluation of the attribute references in `container.node.hello()` occurs left to right, so `container.node` is evaluated without "knowing" that you will later try to call a method on it.

As Patrick Haugh suggests in his answer, you could subclass `int` so that `container.node` is something that *behaves* like the number 3 but also has a `.hello()` method.  But still you're not causing `container.node` to have different values in different contexts; you're causing it to have one value that combines the features you want across the two contexts.  The value is not actually `3` but a Node instance, which can matter in some situations.  Still, this can often be a legitimate way to achieve a similar effect to what you seem to want.

It is also possible to use `__setattr__` so that `container.node = 3` will set the value to something other than 3 (for instance, to some wrapper object), but that won't change the above.  When you evaluate `container.node`, it can only have one value across all contexts.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to confirm with the experts that it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

Below, I make a `Node` class that is a subclass of `int`, basically just adding a `hello` method. `Container` uses `property` to turn `int` values into `Node`s behind the scenes.

```
class Node(int):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Node, cls).__new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs)
    def hello(self):
        print("Hello!")

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.node = 5
    @property
    def node(self):
        return self._node
    @node.setter
    def node(self, value):
        self._node = Node(value)

container = Container()
container.node = 3
print(container.node)  # 3
container.node.hello()  # Hello!
```

Comment: You can do this, but `container.node` is then not actually 3.  It is a Node instance.  This may or may not matter for the user's purposes.  Also, if you do math on it (like `x = container.node + 2`), you'll get back a regular int instead of a Node, which may be confusing.

Comment: @BrenBarn It's not difficult to add methods allowing for more type-safe arithmetic on these objects. I think the real concern there is that `Node(1) + Node (2)` doesn't return a `Node`.  I don't think `Node(3)` not *being* `3` is a real problem.  At most, that might trip up a novice using `is` who didn't really mean it.